# White space between <li> items in IE

Tags: list, css, internet-explorer, whitespace

I have the following list:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="page1.html">Page 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="page4.html">Page 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="page5.html">Page 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

The CSS for this is as follows:

```
ul.nav {
    text-align:right;
}

ul.nav li {
    display:inline;
}

ul.nav li a {
    font-family:'Gill Sans MT','Gill Sans', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    margin-left:20px;
    border-top:3px rgba(255,255,255,0) solid;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#333333;
}
```

Now, in Chrome each `<li>` is separated by 20px (The margin-left), and that's it. But in IE 11, and lower, it's a bit more. Even if I take the margin-left to be 0px, I get white space in IE, but not in Chrome. I have then been reading about similar problems, where I it was suggested that I put the `<li>` on the same line, so like:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="page1.html">Page 1</a></li><li><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li><li><a href="page3.html">Page 3</a></li><li><a href="page4.html">Page 4</a></li><li><a href="page5.html">Page 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

And if I do that, it fixes the IE issue.

So my question is: Is that really the way to do it ? It seems so stupid, that I have to ugly-up my code, in order for IE to get that I do not want white space when I haven't asked it to do anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the big gotcha with `inline-block`

Some people use html comments to split lines:

```
<li>...<!---
--><li>
```

There are some tricks you can try like `font-size: 0` and whitespace changes, but ultimate `floating` is a lot less problematic.

[Fighting space between inline-block](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)